# trigger a rollout via an API call on Openshift 4

Tags: openshift

I have a deployment config on openshift 4, I want to lunch a number of pods via openshift API, can I lunch a new rollout of this deployment config via a curl API call, if yes how?

Comment: Hi, What exactly you wanna do ?

Comment: `oc  rollout -h` might be helpful and if you know the exact command then you just need to add `-v=6` flag to get the curl command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a curl example:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
  <API-Address>/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/<Namespace>/deploymentconfigs/<DeploymentConfig-Name>/instantiate \
  -d '{"latest": true, "force": true, "name": "<DeploymentConfig-Name>"}'
```